# Rotate a Triangle around its center with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry

It's late on a Friday and I'm scratching my head on this one.

I'm trying to draw an equilateral triangle and rotate it around it's center but for some reason I'm having trouble determining it's center point.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/braitsch/TV9zK/31/) where you can see how I'm translating to the center of the canvas and then drawing the Triangle out from there using the equation:

```
var width = 30;
var height = width * (Math.sqrt(3)/2);
```

To determine the ratio of width / height.

What am I missing here? Any thoughts would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're rotating around (0, 0), which in this case isn't the center of your triangle.

A triangle with vertices (0, -h / 2), (w / 2, h / 2), (-w / 2, h / 2) has a center that's the average of those three positions. Fairly obviously, (1/3)(-h / 2) + (2/3)(h / 2) = h / 6. So that's the *actual* y-coordinate of the center of your triangle.

One solution might be to move your triangle to (0, (-2/3)*h), (w / 2, h / 3), (-w / 2, h / 3).

Comment: Awesome, I just drew the triangle from the coordinates you suggested and it works beautifully. However would you mind clarifying how I might calculate the y-coordinate of the center from my triangle with vertices (0, -h / 2), (w / 2, h / 2), (-w / 2, h / 2)? Your equation of (1/3)(-h / 2) + (2/3)(h / 2) = h / 6 wasn't too clear to me. Thanks!

Comment: It's the same logic you use to average three numbers: add up the x and y component of each vertex and divide by the number of things you added up. In your case, you had two vertices whose y-component was h/2 and one vertex whose y-component was -h/2. Intuitively, you can see that the average of those values is slightly above zero; mathematically, that's (h/2 + h/2 - h/2)/3, which I just wrote as (2/3)(h / 2) + (1/3)(-h / 2).

Comment: Incidentally, if you ever generalize to non-equilateral triangles, there are actually multiple ways to get a "center" for a triangle, which have different geometric interpretations and may work better for different purposes: http://www.jimloy.com/geometry/centers.htm

Comment: Many many thanks for your help. Appreciate you taking the time to help clarify. Cheers!